# Powerbi power query column splitting issue

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

i'm hoping someone can help with this one. I'm reasonably competent with powerBI although my power query skills are limited.

I have some data i've imported into powerBI, similar to below. So Users in 1st column and groups in 2nd column. Each group cell can have many entries (or not so many).

```
User     Groups
---------------
user1    g1 g2
user2    g2 g4
user3    g1 g3
```

I could split the data simply, but i want it to look like the below:

```
User G1 G2 G3 G4
----------------
User1 x x 
User2   x      x
User3 x     x
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on this? I could modify the input source data to achieve it, using excel VBA probably, but that means an extra step as i already have the data in powerBI in the format I use for other modelling. Ideally I want to use power query or similar to manipulate to get the results above. I'm just not sure how!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WKi1OLTJU0lFKN1RIN1KK1YGIGIFEjBTSTeAixlA1xkqxsQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [User = _t, Groups = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"User", type text}, {"Groups", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Groups", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Groups"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Groups", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Custom", each "x"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[Groups]), "Groups", "Custom", List.Max),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"User", "g1", "g2", "g3", "g4"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: David,  thank you so much. Didn't occur to me to split by rows rather than columns and go from there.  Superb!!